# How to recover the password for a particular user account on my linux pc

Tags: linux, passwords, linux-kernel, sudo

I have a linux pc on which several users are configured to login. for the same PC i have the root access (username and password). I have lost one of the user accounts password. How to get back the password for that particular user account.
I have tried the following being a root user

```
passwd <login name>
Enter new password
confirm new password
```

But its not fruitful
could you please suggest some ways of recoverng the password.

Also,I got to know that passwords are stored in /etc/shadow file in encrypted form. Does anyone know how to get the decrypted form of encrypted password.

Comment: This question doesn't really seem to be about programming; I think it would be more appropriate for another site in the Stack Overflow network - perhaps ServerFault?

Comment: Why do you need to know the passwords of others?

Comment: It is not *encrypted*, it is *hashed*. That's a difference, encryption implies that it can be decrypted, which is not the case, as a hash is a one-way function with no means to reverse the process.

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of storing hashed passwords in `/etc/shadow` is so that it is not possible to retrieve the plaintext password, so there is no way to determine what the current password is. Your only option is to reset the password using `passwd <username>` as root.

Comment: This is wrong, see the answer from OmnipotentEntity: https://superuser.com/questions/439136/how-to-recover-the-password-for-a-particular-user-account-on-my-linux-pc/439150#439150

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to try to brute force it, the hashes are stored in `/etc/shadow`.  They are salted, so a rainbow table attack will likely not work.  You can try `John the Ripper` to brute force it, but unless the word is a dictionary word or otherwise very weak, I do not think you will have much luck.

Comment: This! OP could retrieve the shadow file and get the salt and hash method.

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the command

```
passwd $user
```

where `$user` is replaced with the account username that has lost the password.

If you're just entering `passwd` naked, with no arguments, then `passwd` assumes that you're wanting to change the password of the currently logged in user.

Also, make sure you're using `su root` to start a root shell, running `sudo`, or such.

Comment: this will allow you to change the account password, not recover it, but after that the user can change it by entering passwd in a terminal window.